# Rails 4 and RSpec 3: Testing models and allow_blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm having an issue testing a model validation, `allow_blank`.  I'm relatively new to RSpec, though in this case I think it is the validation that is the problem.

Here is my model:

```
class ComicBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # ensure a user_id is present
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  # ensure that title is present and at least 3 characters long
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 3 }, presence: true

  # ensure publisher is present and is at least 2 characters long
  validates :publisher, length: { minimum: 2 }, presence: true

  # ensure issue number is present and is at least 1 integer long.
  validates :issue_number, length: { minimum: 1 }, numericality: true, presence: true

  # ensure writer is is at least 2 characters long, allow to be blank
  validates :writer, length: {minimum: 2}, allow_blank: true

  # ensure illustrator is is at least 2 characters long, allow to be blank
  validates :illustrator, length: {minimum: 2}, allow_blank: true

  # ensures summary is at least than 100 characters long, allow to be blank
  validates :summary, length: { maximum: 100  }, allow_blank: true
end
```

and here is my spec:

```
describe "Comic Book" do
  it "is valid with a user id, title, publisher name, issue number and summary" do
    comic_book = ComicBook.new(
      user_id:       1,
      title:         'The Best Comic Book',
      publisher:     'IPC',
      issue_number:  1,
      writer:        'GW',
      illustrator:   'GI',
      summary:       'This comic book is good.  That is all.'
    )
    expect(comic_book).to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a user_id" do
    expect(ComicBook.new(user_id: nil)).not_to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a title" do
    expect(ComicBook.new(title: nil)).not_to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a publisher name" do
     expect(ComicBook.new(publisher: nil)).not_to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a issue number" do
    expect(ComicBook.new(issue_number: nil)).not_to be_valid
  end

  it "is valid without a writer" do
    expect(ComicBook.new(writer: "")).to be_valid
  end

  it "is valid without an illustrator" do
    expect(ComicBook.new(illustrator: "" )).to be_valid
  end

  it "is valid without a summary" do
     expect(ComicBook.new(summary: "")).to be_valid
  end
end
```

And the output:

```
Failures:

      1) Comic Book is valid without a summary
         Failure/Error: expect(ComicBook.new(summary: "")).to be_valid
           expected #<ComicBook id: nil, title: nil, publisher: nil, issue_number: nil, summary: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, writer: nil, illustrator: nil> to be valid, but got errors: User can't be blank, Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Title can't be blank, Publisher is too short (minimum is 2 characters), Publisher can't be blank, Issue number is too short (minimum is 1 character), Issue number is not a number, Issue number can't be blank
         # ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) Comic Book is valid without a writer
         Failure/Error: expect(ComicBook.new(writer: " ")).to be_valid
           expected #<ComicBook id: nil, title: nil, publisher: nil, issue_number: nil, summary: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, writer: " ", illustrator: nil> to be valid, but got errors: User can't be blank, Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Title can't be blank, Publisher is too short (minimum is 2 characters), Publisher can't be blank, Issue number is too short (minimum is 1 character), Issue number is not a number, Issue number can't be blank
         # ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      3) Comic Book is valid without an illustrator
         Failure/Error: expect(ComicBook.new(illustrator: "" )).to be_valid
           expected #<ComicBook id: nil, title: nil, publisher: nil, issue_number: nil, summary: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, writer: nil, illustrator: ""> to be valid, but got errors: User can't be blank, Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Title can't be blank, Publisher is too short (minimum is 2 characters), Publisher can't be blank, Issue number is too short (minimum is 1 character), Issue number is not a number, Issue number can't be blank
         # ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 1.06 seconds (files took 2.36 seconds to load)
    10 examples, 3 failures

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:40 # Comic Book is valid without a summary
    rspec ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:32 # Comic Book is valid without a writer
    rspec ./spec/models/comic_book_spec.rb:36 # Comic Book is valid without an illustrator
```

As you can see the last three specs are not passing.
I have tried setting the values of illustrator, writer and summary to `nil` as well with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a new ComicBook, only the properties you explicitly set are set. This means that if you add a new field and validator, the constructors in every test will need to have that new field. To simplify this, and follow DRY, use only one constructor.

```
before :each do
  @comic_book = ComicBook.new(...) # Fill in values here
end
```

Then, in each test, modify only the parts of the object you are testing.

```
it "is invalid without a issue number" do
  @comic_book.issue_number = nil
  expect(@comic_book).not_to be_valid
end
```

Now if you change your model, you will only have to change the one constructor in the `before` block.

To simplify this further, you can extract that information using something like [`FactoryGirl`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). Once that is set up (read the docs for instructions) you can write something similar to what you have done here and it will act like you expect.

```
it "is invalid without a issue number" do
  comic_book = FactoryGirl.build(:comic_book, issue_number: nil)
  expect(comic_book).not_to be_valid
end
```

The extra information hiding can make your tests cleaner, but the setup might not be worth it for a small project.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a very concise explanation and has cleared up some concepts I've been having trouble with in general.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is not valid. You aren't just checking for the presence of errors on summary, but the entire model. This will fail on title presence, for example, on the last one. You can check for the specific error, or maybe just use something like https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers to automate much of the process.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but in that case why are the first specs passing?

Comment: I think I see, because in the first tests I'm testing to see if the model is not valid, and it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are expecting the entire ComicBook record to be valid:

```
it "is valid without a summary" do
  expect(ComicBook.new(summary: "")).to be_valid
end
```

In that example, the ComicBook will still be invalid because a :user_id is required.  Check that you don't get any errors on the :summary attribute instead:

```
it "is has no errors on summary" do
  comic_book = ComicBook.new(summary: '')
  comic_book.valid?
  expect(comic_book.errors[:summary).to be_empty
end
```